# Ray not distributing remote functions to all nodes on local machine

Tags: python-3.x, ray

I am trying to distribute a list of files via their paths to a remote Ray function that reads the file and then calls other functions in custom libraries to be executed on the files. However, when I examine progress in the Ray UI only 2 of 8 nodes are being used and time to process is consistent with fewer than 8 nodes doing the processing. I am very new to Ray so am having trouble understanding what is happening. Here is an example:

```
import ray
import custom_lib 
import glob

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def remote_func(path):
    with open(path) as file:
    s = file.read()
    custom_data = custom_lib.custom_func(s)
    return custom_data

paths = glob.glob('/location/of/text/files/'+'//*.txt')
data = ray.get([remote_func.remote(p) for p in paths])
```

I am using python 3.8 and ray 1.2. Thanks in advance!